# sqlite how to set, unset, destroy user session

Tags: javascript, react-native, sqlite

In php, one can set user session_start, session_set, session_unset, session_destroy
How can I do these in react native sqlite? Or are there equivalents or alternatives to these

I have searched and could not find solutions. Unfortunately I couldn't get alternatives.

Comment: react-native-sqlite-storage is _just_ for using sqlite, the database, it's not session management. If you want session management, you've been searching for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, session management functions are used to handle user sessions on the server. PHP is a server-side language, so it runs on the server where it can securely manage session data and interact with databases.

JavaScript, when used on the client-side (such as in React), runs in the user's browser. It lacks direct access to server resources, including databases, due to security concerns. This is because allowing client-side JavaScript to access databases can expose sensitive data and create vulnerabilities.

Node.js, despite being JavaScript, operates on the server. It provides a runtime environment that allows JavaScript to run on the server-side. This is in contrast to client-side JavaScript. Node.js can securely interact with databases and handle operations like session management, just like PHP, ensuring data security and proper access control.

Comment: note that the question is about React Native, i.e. the Android and IOS app development framework, not about React, the browser UI framework.

Comment: session ease coding, making tracking of user, data request, update (peculiar to user) etc on server easy. e.g. $_SESSION["id"] or $_SESSION["username"] can be used to retrieve data from server to user without js code at the front end
I am aware of getting token from server end and storing on local storage. This may be an alternative but I don't consider local storage a safe place for such.
So also useContext but this is also at front end.
If we can use sqlite to set a database, tables and interact with our database, can't sqlite also set up a session or alternative to session